# Will Wpf application takes default dpi setting, if user system not support PerMonitorV2?

Tags: c#, wpf, dpi

I was created the WPF application and enabling the dpi settings as **"PerMonitorV2"**. Now PerMonitorV2 will be supported in **windows10 anniversary version or higher**. In this case if I use the application in windows7 or window8, Whether the WPF application will take the Default **"SystemAware"**? Are we need to set **SystemAware** manually respective to the OS?

Appmanifest code:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
        PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor
      </dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Comment: If i recall correctly pre Win10 OS will just look at the dpiAware setting and you have set it to true already.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process Key sentence " On older versions of Windows, the newer <dpiAwareness> tag will be ignored."

Comment: Thank you for your info. I have another doubt regarding DPI. What is the  difference between SystemAware and PerMonitorV2. I didn't any difference in between both. I have tried out by moving the application to the extended monitor of different DPI still no difference is there. How can I see the difference visually?

Comment: If a window's size does not change when you move the window between monitors of different DPI settings, DPI scalling is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/main/PerMonitorDPI/readme.md